# Saving files in flash memory

Tags: android

how can I get the path for the folder where my app can save large JPG files?.  getExternalStorageDirectory()  works fine only when SD Card is present, but what happens when SD is removed or the harware don't have SD Card slot. 
thanks

Comment: To clarify, when SD is removed in my tab I still can save JPG , but I have to use (manually) the path "mnt/flash". In my HTC One S (no SD Card slot) I have to use "mnt/sdcard", I also found the path manually, Is there any way to do this automatically for differents dispositives?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the getFilesDir() method of a [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir%28%29). From a context you can also use methods to get the cache directory, external cache directory, and the external files directory. An Activity is also a context, so you can use these methods from inside one.

The getFilesDir() method gives you the folder where your files will be accessible only from your application and will be always available. However, you should use the cache directory instead, when possible. This way you will avoid making the system run out of space.

**EDIT:**

**My answer**: Almost always a device will either have an SD card or built-in external storage. When it's built-in, it's still called external storage. To check whether the external storage is removable (SD card) or built-in you can use isExternalStorageRemovable() in Environment. 
Basically, you shouldn't place large files on the internal memory. *There is no public folder in the internal memory.* If a device doesn't have external storage, it's simply not capable of doing certain things. Simple as that. So one option you have when there is no external storage is to inform the user about it and ask them to insert a card. You don't have to handle this case, let the user handle it.

**The answer you asked for**: Try using [getDir(String name, int mode)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDir%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) and/or [openFileOutput(String name, int mode)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) of a Context object, and for mode use MODE_WORLD_READABLE or MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE. Also check [Using the Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).

You are facing intended limitations of the platform that are there for the good of everyone.

Comment: hi, I want these JPGS be accesible from other apps (mainly image gallery). I  think getFilesDir() is not the solution of my problem because I want save my JPGS in same folder (or similar) than standard camera uses, (DCIM). thanks

Comment: Android is intentionally designed to not allow this, and that's for a reason. Sorry to say it, but it seems your app should either require external storage, or it should offer limited functionality when there is no external storage. Check the edit in my post.

Answer (score 0):

You could either require external directory to exist, or you can store to the internal directory. If you choose to permit both, I suggest you store a flag in internal space to indicate that you've stored something externally, so that if external storage is not present you can take appropriate action.

Answer (score 0):

As you are Saving Large JPG files, its is better to save it  in external storage because Phone  has very small internal memory and  its all effect the performance of phone.